# Video.js stuck on loading on chrome

Tags: loading, vlc, http-live-streaming, video.js

How are you.
I am using Vide.js to play m3u8. this file contain multiple stream urls.
This is code what I have tried

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Video.js 6.2.8</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .m{ width: 740px; height: 400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 100px; }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="m">
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="740" height="400"
          poster="images/pic01.jpg" data-setup="{}" muted="muted">
        </video>
    </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            videojs.Hls.MAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 30;
            var option={};
            var myPlayer = videojs('my-video',option,function onPlayerReady(){
                var myPlayer = this;
                myPlayer.src({src: "http://disney.lat/assets/m3ufile/ok.m3u8", type: "application/x-mpegURL"});
                this.play();
            });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It loading and download data. I see data continuously downloading in chrome inspector network tab.
[image]

In photo, it transferred 132 MB, but it shows loading icon and continue loading, not starting to play.
There is one interesting thing, when I open VLC player and play that m3u8 file, chrome browser stop loading and start playing.
It's strange.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem where some segments of the playlist were downloaded and then only the m3u8 file was downloaded repeatedly. I resolved by changing the cache policies in the `.htaccess` file on the server. In my case, I just deleted the `ExpiresDefault` line and the problem was solved.